# How to write relative unix path in xml

Tags: xml, linux, path

when i run a process in unix the path points to /abc/1/2/3

I am setting a property in an xml for a process which run in path. 
One property i have

```
< property name="log.path" value="/abc/4/5"/ >
```

Problem is that i cannot give absolute path("/abc/1/2/3") as above. i have to give something like "../../../4/5".

```
< property name="log.path" value="../../../4/5"/ >
```

my questions is why the above evaluation is not working? currently it is considering the path given in value as constant.

Comment: Tough to answer this without details about why you're restricted in this manner. Provide some more detail please? :)

Comment: please add a comment if somebody negates it , so that i can get to know the cause.

Comment: your question is still not clear. Why can't you give an absolute path?

Comment: i cannot give the absolute path because "abc" is a hostname and it will vary depending on the machine where it runs.

Comment: So just strip the hostname and then your absolute path is "/4/5"

Answer (score 2):

XML is just a standardised format for storing structured data... it specifies nothing about what element attributes *mean*, since it has no idea that (for example) that attribute is semantically a Unix-type path.

So this isn't really a question about XML, it's about how the application that's reading the XML handles specified paths. For example (as mentioned), what directory it considers current will affect the interpretation of relative paths... assuming that relative paths are actually parsed correctly by the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

In short, what you are doing is absolutely right. If it is not working, the problem may be that when the application executes, it executes in a different folder than the one you are expecting.

Can be resolved if you provide more details

Tanmay

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's analyze this.

> when i run a process in unix the path points to /abc/1/2/3

Now does the executable for the process exist at */abc/1/2/3* or is */abc/1/2/3* the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_working_directory) for your process?

If current working directory for the process is */abc/1/2/3* and the process reads that XML file and tries to use the path in there directly with a system call like *open* then the relative path notation *../../../4/5* should work. If however the path */abc/1/2/3* is not the current working directory and just the location of the executable then *../../../4/5* can not work as the current working directory is not */abc/1/2/3* and relative paths always work against the current working directory.

Make sure to check if */abc/1/2/3* is truly the current working directory and not just the executable location.